# How can I write a unit test assertion that checks for an error with specified identifier and with a specific message?

Tags: matlab, unit-testing

I'm using the new [unit testing framework](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab-unit-test-framework.html) for MATLAB that was introduced in R2013a, matlab.unittest. I would like to write an assertion that both of the following things happen:

1. An exception with a specified identifier is raised.
2. The message of that exception satisfies some condition.

I've found the [`verifyError`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlab.unittest.qualifications.verifiable.verifyerror.html) method but that only appears to allow me to check the identifier, or the error metaclass.

The other option appears to be [`verifyThat`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlab.unittest.qualifications.verifiable.verifythat.html) with the [`Throws`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlab.unittest.constraints.html#zmw57dd0e132330) constraint. That seems more promising but the documentation of `Throws` appears somewhat sparse and I cannot work out how to make it do what I want.

I realise that I could add the message text to the error identifier but I don't really want to do that. The message text comes from a native library that is called using a mex file. And the text is formatted with spaces and so on. The text could be quite long and would make a mess of the error identifier.

So, is it possible to achieve what I want, and if so how?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is no ready function to do that. Here is one way to hack it.

Consider the following function we are testing. It throws a specific error on non-numeric inputs:

#### increment.m

```
function out = increment(x)
    if ~isa(x,'numeric')
        error('increment:NonNumeric', 'Input must be numeric.');
    end
    out = x + 1;
end
```

Here is the unit-test code:

#### IncrementTest.m

```
classdef IncrementTest < matlab.unittest.TestCase
    methods (Test)
        function testOutput(t)
            t.verifyEqual(increment(1), 2);
        end
        function testClass(t)
            t.verifyClass(increment(1), class(2));
        end
        function testErrId(t)
            t.verifyError(@()increment('1'), 'increment:NonNumeric');
        end

        function testErrIdMsg(t)
            % expected exception
            expectedME = MException('increment:NonNumeric', ...
                'Input must be numeric.');

            noErr = false;
            try
                [~] = increment('1');
                noErr = true;
            catch actualME
                % verify correct exception was thrown
                t.verifyEqual(actualME.identifier, expectedME.identifier, ...
                    'The function threw an exception with the wrong identifier.');
                t.verifyEqual(actualME.message, expectedME.message, ...
                    'The function threw an exception with the wrong message.');
            end

            % verify an exception was thrown
            t.verifyFalse(noErr, 'The function did not throw any exception.');
        end
    end
end
```

The use of the try/catch block is inspired by `assertExceptionThrown` function from the old [xUnit Test Framework](http://web.archive.org/web/20160303170034/http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/22846-matlab-xunit-test-framework) by Steve Eddins.
(*Update*: the framework appears to have been removed from the File Exchange, I guess to encourage using the new built-in framework instead. Here is a popular fork of the old xUnit if you're interested: [psexton/matlab-xunit](https://github.com/psexton/matlab-xunit)).

If you want to give a bit more flexibility in testing the error message, use [`verifyMatches`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlab.unittest.qualifications.verifiable.verifymatches.html) instead to match against strings using regular expressions.

---

Also if you are feeling adventurous, you could study the [`matlab.unittest.constraints.Throws`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlab.unittest.constraints.throws-class.html) class and create your [own version](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlab.unittest.constraints.html) which checks the error message in addition to the error id.

```
ME = MException('error:id', 'message');

import matlab.unittest.constraints.Throws
%t.verifyThat(@myfcn, Throws(ME));
t.verifyThat(@myfcn, ThrowsWithId(ME));
```

where `ThrowsWithId` is your extended version

---

## EDIT:

ok so I went through the code of [`matlab.unittest.constraints.Throws`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlab.unittest.constraints.throws-class.html) and I implemented a [custom](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/create-custom-constraint.html) [`Constraint`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlab.unittest.constraints.constraint-class.html) class.

The class is similar to [`Throws`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlab.unittest.constraints.throws-class.html). It takes an [`MException`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mexception-class.html) instance as input, and checks whether the function handle being tested throws a similar exception (checking both the error id and message). It can be used with any of the assertion methods:

- `testCase.assertThat(@fcn, ThrowsErr(ME))`
- `testCase.assumeThat(@fcn, ThrowsErr(ME))`
- `testCase.fatalAssertThat(@fcn, ThrowsErr(ME))`
- `testCase.verifyThat(@fcn, ThrowsErr(ME))`

To create a subclass from the abstract class [`matlab.unittest.constraints.Constraint`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlab.unittest.constraints.constraint-class.html), we must implement the two functions of the interface: [`satisfiedBy`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlab.unittest.constraints.constraint.satisfiedby.html) and [`getDiagnosticFor`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlab.unittest.constraints.constraint.getdiagnosticfor.html). Also note that we instead inherit from another abstract class `FunctionHandleConstraint` since it provides a few helper methods to work with function handles.

The constructor takes the expected exception (as an `MException` instance), and an optional input specifying the number of output arguments with which to invoke the function handle being tested.

The code:

```
classdef ThrowsErr < matlab.unittest.internal.constraints.FunctionHandleConstraint
    %THROWSERR  Constraint specifying a function handle that throws an MException
    %
    % See also: matlab.unittest.constraints.Throws

    properties (SetAccess = private)
        ExpectedException;
        FcnNargout;
    end

    properties (Access = private)
        ActualException = MException.empty;
    end

    methods
        function constraint = ThrowsErr(exception, numargout)
            narginchk(1,2);
            if nargin < 2, numargout = 0; end
            validateattributes(exception, {'MException'}, {'scalar'}, '', 'exception');
            validateattributes(numargout, {'numeric'}, {'scalar', '>=',0, 'nonnegative', 'integer'}, '', 'numargout');
            constraint.ExpectedException = exception;
            constraint.FcnNargout = numargout;
        end
    end

    %% overriden methods for Constraint class
    methods
        function tf = satisfiedBy(constraint, actual)
            tf = false;
            % check that we have a function handle
            if ~constraint.isFunction(actual)
                return
            end
            % execute function (remembering that its been called)
            constraint.invoke(actual);
            % check if it never threw an exception
            if ~constraint.HasThrownAnException()
                return
            end
            % check if it threw the wrong exception
            if ~constraint.HasThrownExpectedException()
                return
            end
            % if we made it here then we passed
            tf = true;
        end

        function diag = getDiagnosticFor(constraint, actual)
            % check that we have a function handle
            if ~constraint.isFunction(actual)
                diag = constraint.getDiagnosticFor@matlab.unittest.internal.constraints.FunctionHandleConstraint(actual);
                return
            end
            % check if we need to execute function
            if constraint.shouldInvoke(actual)
                constraint.invoke(actual);
            end
            % check if it never threw an exception
            if ~constraint.HasThrownAnException()
                diag = constraint.FailingDiagnostic_NoException();
                return
            end
            % check if it threw the wrong exception
            if ~constraint.HasThrownExpectedException()
                diag = constraint.FailingDiagnostic_WrongException();
                return
            end
            % if we made it here then we passed
            diag = PassingDiagnostic(constraint);
        end
    end

    %% overriden methods for FunctionHandleConstraint class
    methods (Hidden, Access = protected)
        function invoke(constraint, fcn)
            outputs = cell(1,constraint.FcnNargout);
            try
                [outputs{:}] = constraint.invoke@matlab.unittest.internal.constraints.FunctionHandleConstraint(fcn);
                constraint.ActualException = MException.empty;
            catch ex
                constraint.ActualException =  ex;
            end
        end
    end

    %% private helper functions
    methods (Access = private)
        function tf = HasThrownAnException(constraint)
            tf = ~isempty(constraint.ActualException);
        end

        function tf = HasThrownExpectedException(constraint)
            tf = metaclass(constraint.ActualException) <= metaclass(constraint.ExpectedException) && ...
                strcmp(constraint.ActualException.identifier, constraint.ExpectedException.identifier) && ...
                strcmp(constraint.ActualException.message, constraint.ExpectedException.message);
        end

        function diag = FailingDiagnostic_NoException(constraint)
            import matlab.unittest.internal.diagnostics.ConstraintDiagnosticFactory;
            import matlab.unittest.internal.diagnostics.DiagnosticSense;
            subDiag = ConstraintDiagnosticFactory.generateFailingDiagnostic(...
                constraint, DiagnosticSense.Positive);
            subDiag.DisplayDescription = true;
            subDiag.Description = 'The function did not throw any exception.';
            subDiag.DisplayExpVal = true;
            subDiag.ExpValHeader = 'Expected exception:';
            subDiag.ExpVal = sprintf('id  = ''%s''\nmsg = ''%s''', ...
                constraint.ExpectedException.identifier, ...
                constraint.ExpectedException.message);
            diag = constraint.generateFailingFcnDiagnostic(DiagnosticSense.Positive);
            diag.addCondition(subDiag);
        end

        function diag = FailingDiagnostic_WrongException(constraint)
            import matlab.unittest.internal.diagnostics.ConstraintDiagnosticFactory;
            import matlab.unittest.internal.diagnostics.DiagnosticSense;
            if strcmp(constraint.ActualException.identifier, constraint.ExpectedException.identifier)
                field = 'message';
            else
                field = 'identifier';
            end
            subDiag =  ConstraintDiagnosticFactory.generateFailingDiagnostic(...
                constraint, DiagnosticSense.Positive, ...
                sprintf('''%s''',constraint.ActualException.(field)), ...
                sprintf('''%s''',constraint.ExpectedException.(field)));
            subDiag.DisplayDescription = true;
            subDiag.Description = sprintf('The function threw an exception with the wrong %s.',field);
            subDiag.DisplayActVal = true;
            subDiag.DisplayExpVal = true;
            subDiag.ActValHeader = sprintf('Actual %s:',field);
            subDiag.ExpValHeader = sprintf('Expected %s:',field);
            diag = constraint.generateFailingFcnDiagnostic(DiagnosticSense.Positive);
            diag.addCondition(subDiag);
        end

        function diag = PassingDiagnostic(constraint)
            import matlab.unittest.internal.diagnostics.ConstraintDiagnosticFactory;
            import matlab.unittest.internal.diagnostics.DiagnosticSense;
            subDiag = ConstraintDiagnosticFactory.generatePassingDiagnostic(...
                constraint, DiagnosticSense.Positive);
            subDiag.DisplayExpVal = true;
            subDiag.ExpValHeader = 'Expected exception:';
            subDiag.ExpVal = sprintf('id  = ''%s''\nmsg = ''%s''', ...
                constraint.ExpectedException.identifier, ...
                constraint.ExpectedException.message);
            diag = constraint.generatePassingFcnDiagnostic(DiagnosticSense.Positive);
            diag.addCondition(subDiag);
        end
    end

end
```

Here is an example usage (using the same function as before):

```
t = matlab.unittest.TestCase.forInteractiveUse;

ME = MException('increment:NonNumeric', 'Input must be numeric.');
t.verifyThat(@()increment('5'), ThrowsErr(ME))

ME = MException('MATLAB:TooManyOutputs', 'Too many output arguments.');
t.verifyThat(@()increment(5), ThrowsErr(ME,2))
```

### UPDATE:

The internals of some of the classes have changed a bit since I posted this answer. I updated the code above to work with the latest MATLAB R2016a. See the revision history if you want the older version.

Comment: I must say that a better way would be to only test the error identifier, ignoring the message. The message string is after all only used as a human readable description and should not be compared against in the first place.

Comment: Thanks for this. What you are doing is the same as what I am already doing. I'm looking for something better. I'm looking for a single `verifyXXX` type of call. The reason that I don't want to use the error identifier alone is that the same ID is being used from all errors raised by a native library called by my mex file. And it's just not convenient to wrap them all up with different IDs.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: see my edit, now it should be possible to use `t.verifyThat(@fcn, ThrowsErr(ME))`

Comment: Thank you ever so much for this. I can see you put in a lot of effort. I really appreciate it and it will be very useful to me. It's a shame your hard work only nets you my upvote but I guess that's just life in the backwaters of the matlab tag!  ;-)

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: glad I could help. No worries we're used to it here in MATLAB tag, certainly not as high traffic as C# or Java.. Besides I've been wanting to explore the new unittest framework, so this was a perfect opportunity for me to dig through the code :)